# MS SQL Server error on log in

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2014

I installed MS Sql server 2014 and every log in, it doesn't allow me to log in without typing my laptop password on the sql server settings on SERVICES.

[image: Please see picture below:]

This is where I type my laptop password:
[image]

After typing and clicking OK, I should right click and click start manually. After doing this, I can now login to SQL server. This process is kind of time consuming, so do you guys have any other solution for this? Thanks..

Btw, this is the error that I am getting without doing the process above,
[image]

Comment: This happens every time you restart your laptop? Are there any errors in the windows logs relating to SQL Server events?

Comment: Yes. How can I see that?

Comment: When you setup your server, did you select "Windows Authentication mode" or "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".  If later, can you login to SSMS as sa user?

Comment: Windows Authentication mode only. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should leave the Password blank when using  the "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" virtual account for a service.

Go back to Services Login, click in both password boxes and press delete, then click OK.

Comment: So I need to remove the password on Service? I didn't input any password there. After installing, there's already a password there but I'll try that out.

Comment: If it still gives a problem, switch it to Local System account, then back to "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" with empty passwords.

Comment: After deleting passwords and clicking apply, the passwords come back. lol. I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: That's ok, you shouldn't need to do anything else in services.  Start SSMS and try to connect to server.  What happens?

Comment: Hmm I included the picture above. Cannot connect to my local instance :/

Comment: PBSS-xxx is your local computer name?  Try connecting to just "."  (just a period).  Does that work?

Comment: That did not work, I think this error has something to do with the administration rights in my office.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147985/discussion-between-gordon-bell-and-christina-g).

Comment: after installing the patch for sqlserver 2014, it worked fine. Thanks for all the help :)